# Grid Serializer issue in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid

This issue find magento admin area grid serializer.
When i selected row on grid. grid serializer hidden field not updating. But if i unchecked selected row that will changed the hidden field value.

I just followed following examples

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-grid-serializer-ajax-grids/

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/

Don't know the issue in here

Please some one help me on this issue

[app\code\community\Muaw\Prescription\Block\Adminhtml\Groups\Edit\Tab\Question.php]

```
class Muaw_Prescription_Block_Adminhtml_Groups_Edit_Tab_Question extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('questionsGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_questions' => 1));
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);
}

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    if ($column->getId() == 'in_questions') {
        $questionIds = $this->_getSelectedQuestions();
        if (empty($questionIds)) {
            $questionIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $questionIds));
        } else {
            if ($questionIds) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', array('nin' => $questionIds));
            }
        }
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/question')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('in_questions', array(
        'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'name' => 'in_questions',
        'field_name' => 'questions[]',
        'values' => $this->_getSelectedQuestions(),
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable' => true,
        'width' => '60',
        'index' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('question', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Question'),
        'index' => 'question',
        'align' => 'left',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _getSelectedQuestions()
{
    $customers = array_keys($this->getSelectedQuestions());
    return $customers;
}

public function getSelectedQuestions()
{
    $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if (!isset($tm_id)) {
        $tm_id = 0;
    }
    $questions = array();
    $groupq = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $tm_id);
    foreach ($groupq as $group) {
        $questions[] = $group->getQuestionId();
    }
    $custIds = array();

    foreach ($questions as $cust) {
        $custIds[$cust] = array('id' => $cust);
    }
    return $custIds;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->_getData('grid_url') ? $this->_getData('grid_url') : $this->getUrl('*/*/questionsGrid', array('_current' => true));
}
}
```

[app\code\community\Muaw\Prescription\Block\Adminhtml\Groups\Edit\Tabs.php]

```
class Muaw_Prescription_Block_Adminhtml_Groups_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('form_tabs');
    $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group Information'));
}


protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->addTab('form_section', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Groups Information'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Details'),
        'content' => $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tab_main')
            ->toHtml(),
    ));

    $this->addTab('questions', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Associated Questions'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/questionstab', array('_current' => true)),
        'content' => $this->getLayout(),
        'class' => 'ajax',
    ));
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
}
```

[app\code\community\Muaw\Prescription\controllers\Adminhtml\GroupsController.php]

```
class Muaw_Prescription_Adminhtml_GroupsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected function _initAction()
{
    // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('prescription/manage')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group')
        )
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group')
        );
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Group'))
        ->_title($this->__('Manage Group'));

    $this->_initAction();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function QuestionAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Group Questions'))
        ->_title($this->__('Manage Group Questions'));

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('groups/manage')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group Questions'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group Questions')
        )
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group Questions'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group Questions')
        );
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function newAction()
{
    // the same form is used to create and edit
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

public function editAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Group'))
        ->_title($this->__('Manage Group'));

    $model = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');

    $newsId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($newsId) {
        $model->load($newsId);

        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group does not exist.'));
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
        $this->_title($model->getTitle());
        $breadCrumb = Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Edit Item');
    } else {
        $this->_title(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('New Item'));
        $breadCrumb = Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('New Item');
    }

    $this->_initAction()->_addBreadcrumb($breadCrumb, $breadCrumb);

    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model->addData($data);
    }

    Mage::register('question_item', $model);

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function saveAction()
{
    $redirectPath = '*/*';
    $redirectParams = array();

    // check if data sent
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (isset($data['links'])) {
        $customers = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['questions']);
    }
    //print_r($customers);exit;
    if ($data) {

        $data = $this->_filterPostData($data);
        $model = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');

        if (empty($data['pid'])) {
            $arr = array();
            $arr['form_key'] = $data['form_key'];
            $arr['name'] = $data['name'];
            $model->addData($arr);
            $out = $model->save()->getId();
        } else {
            $arr = array();
            $arr['form_key'] = $data['form_key'];
            $arr['id'] = $data['pid'];
            $arr['name'] = $data['name'];
            $model->load($data['pid'])->addData($arr);
            $model->setId($data['pid'])->save();
            $out = $data['pid'];
        }

        try {
            $hasError = false;
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('The Group has been saved.'));
            // check if 'Save and Continue'
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $redirectPath = '*/*/edit';
                $redirectParams = array('id' => $out);
            }


            $groupq = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $out);
            $sel_question = array();
            foreach ($groupq as $group) {
                if (!empty($group->getQuestionId())) {
                    $sel_question[$group->getId()] = $group->getQuestionId();
                }
            }

            $del_arr = $new_arr = array();
            $del_arr = array_diff($sel_question, $data['questions']);
            $new_arr = array_diff($data['questions'], $sel_question);

            if (!empty($data['questions'])) {
                if (!empty($del_arr)) {
                    foreach ($del_arr as $del => $val) {
                        $id = $del;
                        $model_qgr = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr');
                        try {
                            $model_qgr->setId($id)->delete();
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            //echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $collection = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $out);
                foreach ($collection as $item) {
                    $id = $item->getId();
                    $model_qgr = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr');
                    try {
                        $model_qgr->setId($id)->delete();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        //echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!empty($new_arr)) {
                foreach ($new_arr as $new) {
                    if ($new != 'on') {
                        $new_data = array();
                        $new_data['question_id'] = $new;
                        $new_data['group_id'] = $out;
                        try {
                            $model_qgr = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->setData($new_data);
                            $insertId = $model_qgr->save()->getId();
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            //echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $hasError = true;
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $hasError = true;
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('An error occurred while saving the Group.'));
        }
        if ($hasError) {
            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            $redirectPath = '*/*/edit';
            $redirectParams = array('id' => $data['pid']);
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect($redirectPath, $redirectParams);
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    // check if we know what should be deleted
    $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($itemId) {
        try {
            $model = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');
            $model->load($itemId);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Unable to find a group.'));
            }
            $model->delete();

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('The group has been deleted.')
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e,
                Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('An error occurred while deleting the group.')
            );
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

protected function _initGroups()
{
    $groupModel = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');
    $groupId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0);
    if ($groupId) {
        try {
            $groupModel->load($groupId);
            if (!$groupModel->getId()) {
                throw new Exception($this->__('This group no longer exists'));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    Mage::register('current_group', $groupModel);
    return $groupModel;
}

protected function _isAllowed()
{
    switch ($this->getRequest()->getActionName()) {
        case 'new':
        case 'save':
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('groups/manage/save');
            break;
        case 'delete':
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('groups/manage/delete');
            break;
        default:
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('groups/manage');
            break;
    }
}

protected function _filterPostData($data)
{
    $data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('time_published'));
    return $data;
}

public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

protected function _isAjax()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public function questionsTabAction()
{

    $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $groupq = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $itemId);
    $sel_question = array();
    foreach ($groupq as $group) {
        if (!empty($group->getQuestionId())) {
            $sel_question[] = $group->getQuestionId();
        }
    }

    $saved_question_ids = $sel_question; // your load logic here

    if (!empty($saved_question_ids)) {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
            ->setQuestions($saved_question_ids);
    } else {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
            ->setQuestions($this->getRequest()->getPost('questions', null));
    }

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function questionsGridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->getLayout()
        ->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
        ->setQuestions($this->getRequest()->getPost('questions', null));

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function questionsAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
        ->setQuestions($this->getRequest()->getPost('questions', null));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

[app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\muaw_prescription.xml]

```
<adminhtml_groups_edit>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tabs" name="groups.edit.tabs" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit" name="groups.edit" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_groups_edit>

<adminhtml_groups_questionstab>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tab_question" name="muaw.tab.questions"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="muaw.serializer.questions">
            <reference name="muaw.serializer.questions">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>muaw.tab.questions</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedQuestions</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[questions]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>questions</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
                </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
</adminhtml_groups_questionstab>

<adminhtml_groups_questionsgrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tab_question" name="muaw.tab.questions"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_groups_questionsgrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change file **app\code\community\Muaw\Prescription\Block\Adminhtml\Groups\Edit\Tab\Question.php**

```
class Muaw_Prescription_Block_Adminhtml_Groups_Edit_Tab_Question extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('questionsGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_questions' => 1));
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);
}

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    if ($column->getId() == 'in_questions') {
        $questionIds = $this->_getSelectedQuestions();
        if (empty($questionIds)) {
            $questionIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $questionIds));
        } else {
            if ($questionIds) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', array('nin' => $questionIds));
            }
        }
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/question')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('in_questions', array(
        'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'field_name' => 'in_questions[]',  // questions changed to in_questions
        'values' => $this->_getSelectedQuestions(),
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable' => true,
        'width' => '60',
        'index' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('question', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Question'),
        'index' => 'question',
        'align' => 'left',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _getSelectedQuestions()
{
    $customers = array_keys($this->getSelectedQuestions());
    return $customers;
}

public function getSelectedQuestions()
{
    $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if (!isset($tm_id)) {
        $tm_id = 0;
    }
    $questions = array();
    $groupq = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $tm_id);
    foreach ($groupq as $group) {
        $questions[] = $group->getQuestionId();
    }
    $custIds = array();

    foreach ($questions as $cust) {
        $custIds[$cust] = array('id' => $cust);
    }
    return $custIds;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->_getData('grid_url') ? $this->_getData('grid_url') : $this->getUrl('*/*/questionsGrid', array('_current' => true));
}
}
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Remove 'name' => 'in_questions', .Updated answer check it

Comment: Still same result. Not working